# Sublime Text 3: Set Environment Variable for plugin_host

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

Sublime Text 3 on OSX.

I am writing a plugin that loads up a particularly poorly-written 3rd-party Python module that relies on the value of an Environment Variable to function properly (in particular, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

Of course, I could set this globally, but I would love for the Sublime Plugin to be self-contained. I notice that plugins run in a child process of Sublime itself - is there any way to tell Sublime to provide the `plugin_host` process with a particular Environment Variable before it spins it off?

If not, does anyone know of another way to solve this problem? For performance and simplicity reasons, I would greatly prefer to have the python script be self-contained, rather than calling out to an external script that utilizes the library. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`os.putenv()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.putenv) and [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.environ) for details on setting environment variables from Python. So, for your case, before importing your 3rd-party module, use something like this:

```py
import os
os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/lib/foo:' + os.environ.get('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH')

import third_party
# and so on...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no dice. The Environment Variables need to be set at process fork. Generally, you can apply them by calling the `os.execv*e` family, but you can'd do that from Sublime.

Comment: @BrandonHorst Can you "sub-fork" your plugin process, or would that just make things a royal mess?

Comment: I could, like I suggested in the second-to-last sentence of the question. But that's nasty. I ended up just re-implementing the python library in a less stupid way.