# Sublime 3 build system does not work as I expected

Tags: linux, sublimetext3

I use Sublime Text 3 on my Ubuntu 16.04 for programming in C/C++/Fortran. I have to use Intel compiler which uses some environment variables like MKLROOT to work properly.
When I tried to write my custom build system I found that Sublime does not see all my environment variables that cause problems with compilation. Compare: `printenv` in your shell and the output of test build system like that:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "printenv"
}
```

The question is: how to force Sublime to see all my environment variables?

Comment: [Is it possible to set environment variables in a .sublime-project file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26136660/608639), [Set Environment Variable for plugin_host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21565189/608639), [custom PATH and PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8574919/608639) and [Where Should I Set Environmental Variables For Use By Sublime Text 3](https://superuser.com/q/638283/173513) on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @jww, thanks, first variant looks useful-enough